# If I have a queue (SQS, AMQP), how do I notify my worker servers when there is an object in it?

Tags: python, events, queue, distributed, amqp

A lot of times my queue will remain empty. But when it does fill up, how does that queue notify my server to execute a python script?

I could make it so that the python script hits the queue every 5 seconds, but that's silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a consumer on the queue, which registers a callback. The consumer will then poll the queue and call the callback when an item is received.

You don't say how you're accessing the queue, but a library like [carrot](http://ask.github.com/carrot/introduction.html) does this for you.